# When editing layer, cannot save edits for lines or polygons

Tags: qgis, layers, editing

I am trying to create a shapefile to draw a line.I can toggle edit, but the line does not correspond to the shapefile (when I unstick the layer, the line remains) and the save option is blacked out. The line is not 'selectable' either - once Ihave drawn it I cannot remove it.

I am using QGIS version 2.18.3. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Millie! After you have drawn your line, did you right-click your mouse to stop drawing the line?

Comment: Hi @Joseph, thank you so much for your reply. I wasn't - what a simple fix! :-)

Comment: Most welcome, yes it's very common to forget that when starting out with QGIS :)